# Networking, monitor and limits by data usage based on IP or user

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

In my home in mountain I have a 4g connection and operator has a cap limit of 10GB

I have tablets, phones, pcs, all connected to a router (Netis with no rich functions).(max 10)
And router is connected as a client to a 4G modem.

**My needs is to limit the usage by source IP or / and by a user login. and stop it when globally exceed a cap or everyone exhaust its own cap**
My attempt is to build the system using Linux or BSD.

So I had thought to reconfigure my network with 1 switch + 1 ap for wireless and wired connections. Then enter in a "Box"  and the "Box" is connected via the router to the 4g modem.

```
AP==SWITCH==BOX==ROUTER==4G_modem
```

Now I think that I have to do 2 thing

If I use the IP strategy

Bridge the two lan in the BOX
monitor traffic on the bridge
Count traffics by IP
Compare the count to limits
If exceeded drop the packet.

There are many methods about this but has someone experience in hooking with those?.
this is the useful question which has answers, but is on monitoring:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/44492/ip-process-based-bandwidth-usage-stats-tool-for-linux

and this is a solution a bit too simple

- https://serverfault.com/questions/737219/how-can-i-bring-an-interface-down-once-the-amount-of-data-transferred-reaches-a

If I use the solution with user-name and password i think squid will be the answer but is really able to filter and block user by its own limit.

some similar question are

- https://serverfault.com/questions/380498/view-internet-usage-of-computers-in-my-network
- https://serverfault.com/questions/141015/the-best-software-for-users-internet-usage
- https://serverfault.com/questions/64206/internet-usage-on-k-12-student-laptops
- https://serverfault.com/questions/727362/monitor-bandwith-usage-on-lan
- https://serverfault.com/questions/546709/monitor-http-usage-on-network-from-linux-free
  -https://serverfault.com/questions/356996/monitor-network-traffic-over-centos-router

I think the that the control should be double drop packet if global cap is exceeded and each user has its own cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PFsense for the "BOX" it runs on top of freebsd. It has all the functions you are looking for plus some, all pre-installed in the package except for free-radius. In PFsense the web gui has what's called an RRD graph. This will give you information on any interface with averages by minute, hour, day, week, and year.
[image]

In PFsense I believe what you are looking for is limiting per user via free-radius package, it couldnt be easier to install under the package manager. it's then under Services > freeRADIUS > then under the username created.[image]
if you are going to use the freeRADIUS option the wireless access point needs to be able to support 802.11 EAP (WPA2-Enterprise).
 or

http://www.squidworks.net/2012/08/pfsense-2-0-limiting-users-upload-and-download-speeds-by-limiting-bandwidth/